# Converting python dataframe(pandas) with a timestamp column to R dataframe using rpy2

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I have a pandas dataframe(df) with data as follows

```
                        time      id  locality_id  supply_hours
0  2016-08-31 18:30:00+00:00     NaN          NaN           NaN
1  2016-08-31 19:30:00+00:00     NaN          NaN           NaN
2  2016-08-31 20:30:00+00:00     NaN          NaN           NaN
3  2016-08-31 21:30:00+00:00  453604            1      0.095328
4  2016-08-31 22:30:00+00:00     NaN          NaN           NaN
```

I neet to convert it to R dataframe. According to docs, all I need is

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
rdf=rpy2.robjects.DataFrame(df)
```

But I get the following error when I try it

```
    NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for 
objects of type '<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>'
```

The following succeeds

```
rdf2=rpy2.robjects.DataFrame(df[['locality_id','supply_hours']])
```

So clearly it has some issues with converting time column in the dataframe. How to get this working? I am on rpy2==2.8.3 and pandas== 0.16.2.

Comment: does it work if you convert the `time` column to py datetime? `df['time'] = df['time'].dt.to_pydatetime()`

Comment: Nope. `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<type 'datetime.datetime'>'`

Comment: This is quite old but does using the pandas converter work: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html#converting-dataframes-into-r-objects

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `rdf=rpy2.robjects.DataFrame(df)` use `rdf= pandas2ri.py2ri(df`)
Below is an example that worked for me!

```
p_dataframe  = Some Time Series Dataframe

from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
r_dataframe = pandas2ri.py2ri(p_dataframe)
print(r_dataframe)
```

Comment: Add some description